# Uploading multiple files using jQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-file-upload

I am uploading multiple files in mvc through AJAX/JSON Like,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/eSignature/FileUpload/UploadFiles',
    autoUpload: true,
    done: function (e, data) {
        $('.file_name').html(data.result.name);
        $('.file_type').html(data.result.type);
        $('.file_size').html(data.result.size);
    }
}).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
    var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
    $('.progress .progress-bar').css('width', progress + '%');
});
```

});

and below is my controller logic

```
public ActionResult UploadFiles()
    {
        List<UploadFilesResult> model = new List<UploadFilesResult>();
        int count = Request.Files.Count;

        foreach (string file in Request.Files)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase hpf = Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFileBase;
            if (hpf.ContentLength == 0)
                continue;

            string savedFileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
            hpf.SaveAs(savedFileName);

            model.Add(new UploadFilesResult()
            {
                Name = hpf.FileName,
                Length = hpf.ContentLength,
                Type = hpf.ContentType
            });

        }

        return View();

    }
```

My problem is while iterating through Request.Files; Only one file is shown at a time though I have uploaded multiple files.

After first file is uploaded; then again call to the method is made by itself; Here it shows the second file name and so on for all files? Why it is like that ?

Because, I am updating my model in for loop where only last value is getting stored.

Anything I am missing here ?????????

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to create its your own, when we have thrid party plugins to do the same thing, try [Jquery Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/demos/).

Comment: I have seen that. But we dont want to use flash.